# ERROR 01 Canon Eos 4000D

Tags: canon, error

I get error 01 displayed, I can't take a picture at all. But if I connect the camera to the app and change to manual with AF, I can take pictures. What could be wrong? A defect in the lens?

I'll also add that when it's cold the temperature is in the minus, the camera completely stutters.

Comment: Which lens? Did it work previously? I'm asking because there are compatibility issues with some Canon bodies and third-party lenses. E.g. I have a Sigma 400mm that works in full-open mode and gives Error 01 when stopped down.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Canon site](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_slr/eos-4000d.html?type=errorcode&errordetailid=tcm:14-1334601) Err 01 mean

> The communication between the camera and lens is faulty.

What is recommended:

> Very gently clean the electrical contacts (highlighted in red) on the camera and the lens using a clean and dry cloth
>
> When cleaning the contacts take the following precautions –
>
> - Do not wipe the contacts with a wet cloth
> - Do not touch the contacts directly with your hands. Touching them with your hands could cause corrosion, which would cause the camera to
>   become inoperable
> - When cleaning the contacts on the lens side, be careful not to damage the lens surface